# Audio in Android Studio stop button issue (Kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

currently studying Kotlin and created an app that has 7 buttons (6 are playing certain audio and 7th is the stop button).When i play the first audio the audio starts and when i press stop button the audio stops, but the issue comes if i play the first audio and then the second and the third at same time , the stop button works only for the first audio and the rest keep playing at same time.Thanks for the help in advance.

This is the **main activity & xml**:

````
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var layout = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.parent_layout)
        val animation = layout.background as AnimationDrawable?
        animation?.setEnterFadeDuration(3000)
        animation?.setExitFadeDuration(1000)
        animation?.start()
    }
    fun PlaySoundOnButtons(view: View){
        val sound = view as Button
        val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this@MainActivity,resources.getIdentifier(sound.tag as String,"raw",packageName))
        mediaPlayer.start()
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
            sound.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
        }
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener { sound.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
        }
        val stopSound = findViewById(R.id.stop_btn) as Button
        stopSound.setOnClickListener {
            mediaPlayer.stop()
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying){
                mediaPlayer.stop()
            }
        }     
    }
}

**XML File**:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mix_colours"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:onClick="PlaySoundOnButtons"
                android:tag="one"
                android:text="Hip Hop"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:onClick="PlaySoundOnButtons"
                android:tag="two"
                android:text="Rap"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:onClick="PlaySoundOnButtons"
                android:tag="three"
                android:text="Jazz"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:onClick="PlaySoundOnButtons"
                android:tag="four"
                android:text="Agressive rap"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:onClick="PlaySoundOnButtons"
                android:tag="five"
                android:text="Old school"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:onClick="PlaySoundOnButtons"
                android:tag="six"
                android:text="Underground rap"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/stop_btn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Stop"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_error" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>```
````

Comment: Then you need to find some way to give `stopSound.setOnClickListener` access to all the `MediaPlayer` instances, not just the most recently started one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want playing single audio you need declare the `mediaPlayer` outside of your click function and the function of stop button to `onCreate`

```
lateinit var mediaPlayer:MediaPlayer
    
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    var layout = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.parent_layout)
    val animation = layout.background as AnimationDrawable?
    animation?.setEnterFadeDuration(3000)
    animation?.setExitFadeDuration(1000)
    animation?.start()


    val stopSound = findViewById(R.id.stop_btn) as Button
    stopSound.setOnClickListener {
        if (::mediaPlayer.isInitialized && mediaPlayer.isPlaying){
            mediaPlayer.stop()
        }
    }     
}

fun PlaySoundOnButtons(view: View){
    val sound = view as Button
    
    if (::mediaPlayer.isInitialized && mediaPlayer.isPlaying){
        mediaPlayer.stop()
    }
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this@MainActivity,resources.getIdentifier(sound.tag as String,"raw",packageName))
    mediaPlayer.start()
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
        sound.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
    }
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener { 
        sound.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your buttons call the same click listener, which creates a new `MediaPlayer`, starts it playing, and then sets the stop button to stop that `MediaPlayer` instance.

So the problem is you have one stop button, and it can only stop the last media player that was assigned to it. Every time a new click happens a new player is created, and the stop button forgets whatever player it was handling before. Even if you click the same button twice.

You need to keep track of all your current `MediaPlayer` instances, so your stop button can call `stop()` on all of them. And really, you need to keep track of them anyway, so you can call `release()` and [free up resources](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#create(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.view.SurfaceHolder))

> When done with the `MediaPlayer`, you should call `release()`, to free the resources. If not released, too many `MediaPlayer` instances will result in an exception.

You might want to consider keeping a map of them, and when your click listener is called, try to `get` the media player associated with the `view` that was clicked, creating a new one for that view if one doesn't exist. Then you can iterate over them all to stop (and maybe call `release` on them while you're at it)